# Is a body rotating in equilibrium?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, equilibrium

If a body is performing a uniform rotation, do we consider it to be in equilibrium because of its constant speed? Or not because it has the centripetal force acting upon it so the sum of all forces is non-zero?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uniform Circular motion and Equilibrium](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/678240/)